# Tangent lines of a smooth curve $C \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth curve, given as the zero locus of a homogeneous polynomial $f \in \mathbb{K}[x_0,x_1,x_2]$.

Consider the morphism $\varphi_C:C\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^2$ such that $P\mapsto(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0}(P):\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(P):\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(P))$.

> Find a geometric description of $\varphi_C$.
>
> What does it mean geometrically if $\varphi_C(P)=\varphi_C(Q)$ for two distinct points $P,Q \in C$?

I have an idea for the answer.

Consider the line $l_{C,P}$ of equation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0}(P)x_0+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0}(P)x_1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_0}(P)x_2=0$, which is the tangent line of $C$ on the point $P$.

So, $\varphi_C$ encodes al the tangent lines of $C$, and in particular $\varphi_C(P)$ gives the coefficients of the tangent line on $P$.

Is this the correct answer?

For the second part, it is true that $P$ and $Q$ have the same tangent line, but can we say more than this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, what you write is a correct and  complete answer to the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot

Comment: For the second part: you might be able to say something about the degree of $C$.

Comment: I don't see what I can say about the degree of $f$...

Comment: You restrict it to a line and on that line it has at least four roots, counting multiplicity. That can't be done by every $f$.

Comment: I don't understand what is your idea and where it can lead us. Can you explain briefly this idea of restring the curve $C$ to a line and the roots? Thanks

Comment: Working on small degrees, the first degree that I found and satisfies the condition is 4, for example, $C=Z(yz^3-x^4+2x^2z^2-z^4)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The morphism $\varphi_C$ is best seen as a morphism $\varphi_C:C\rightarrow(\mathbb{P}^2)^*$ from the curve $C\subset \mathbb P^2$ to the dual projective space $(\mathbb{P}^2)^*$, whose typical point  $Q=(a:b:c)\in(\mathbb{P}^2)^*$ corresponds to the line $l_Q\subset \mathbb P^2$ of equation $ax+by+cz=0$.
If $C$ is a line $ax+by+cz=0$, then  the morphism $\varphi_C$ has constant value $\varphi_C(P)=(a:b:c)$ for all $P\in C$.
But in all other cases (if char. $\mathbb K=0$ )  the image of $\varphi_C$ is a curve $C^*\subset (\mathbb{P}^2)^*$, called the dual curve to $C$.
If $C$ has degree $d\gt1$, then $C^*$ has degree $d(d-1)$, an easy consequence of Bézout's theorem.
If you recall that the degree of $C^*$ is its number of points of intersection with a line in $(\mathbb{P}^2)^*$ you obtain the intersting result that there are $n(n-1)
$ tangents to $C$ passing through a given general point of $\mathbb P^2$: this number is classically known as the *class* of $C$.

Finally, let me remark that in order to have a perfect duality between $C$ and $ C^*$ one has to define $\varphi_C$ also for singular $C$ and one then obtains beautifully symmetric formulas relating the invariants of $C $ to those of $C^*$: the [Plücker formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_formula).
Dual curves are explained in elementary books on classical algebraic geometry.
Two excellent ones are Fischer's [Plane Algebraic Curves](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=STML-15)  and Brieskorn-Knörrer's [identically named text](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Plane_Algebraic_Curves.html?id=KLtvNQMVOEYC&redir_esc=y).
Wikipedia  also has a nice article on [Plücker's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_formula)

**Edit**
The number of double tangents to the curve $C$ is the number of ordinary nodes of $C^*$ and that number is, according to the Plücker formulas, $\frac 12 d(d-2)(d-3)(d+3)$.
This number is zero only if $C$ is a conic or a cubic.

Comment: So according to Plucker formulas we can conclude that $C$ is a conic or a cubic? (Recall that $C$ is a curve, ie, $C=Z(f)$)

Comment: How can we argue about this without knowing nothing about this Plucker Formulas? In other words, how can we explain by simple words that fact?

Comment: For example, $C=Z(yz^3-x^4+2x^2z^2-z^4)$ corresponding to the function $y=x^4-2x^2+1$ which have $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ sharing the same tangent line, works

Comment: Ok, now its clear, thanks for helping. Also I found the Trott curve which is a perfect example for this case.